# How to get files/folders from a remote git repository after we delete them from our local repository?

Tags: git, github

I deleted several folders and files from the local repository I have just selected them and deleted them. (including the folders like 'images' , 'config' ..etc and some files which have modifications done by me and not needed anymore)

I tried `git pull upstream master` and `git fetch upstream master` to get those files and folders back to my local repository.

What I did is basically like,

1. I got a repository from git and placed it locally
2. I made some  changes locally to some files and folders
3. I wanted some files to have the older version (what I had after the first step)
4. I thought deleting the files and get them back  and have the fresh copy again from the git (using above commands and unfortunately they are not working)
5. But I can create a new local repository and have a clone of original repo. But It's too much work and then also I will lost changes I made to the remaining files.

`*I have used SVN and there I can delete any file from the repo and when I get an update the file will be back. But I don't know how to do that with GIT.*`

So is there any way  I can get those deleted files back safely and have those fresh copies.?

Note : I did not commit the deletions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frist use `git status` to look what files you have deleted and then use `git checkout filename_or_dir_name` to resume them.

e.g.:

```
# atupal at atupal in /tmp/tmp [18:15:39]
$ git status .
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

  deleted:    a

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
# atupal at atupal in /tmp/tmp [18:15:41]
$ ls           
# atupal at atupal in /tmp/tmp [18:15:47]
$ git checkout .
# atupal at atupal in /tmp/tmp [18:15:51]
$ ls         
a
# atupal at atupal in /tmp/tmp [18:15:55]
$
```

If you have staged modified files by using `git add file_name`, then after `git-checkout` the resumed file is "fresh", other not.

Comment: What If I delete all the files from the repository ? Is there any easy way to get them all ?

Comment: @prime cd to the root dir, and then `git checkout .` to get them all.

Comment: @prime Did you commit the deletion of all files?

Comment: If you commit the deleted files, after git-checkout you will stay the modifies, Other you will lose your modifies.

Comment: No I did not commit the changes

Comment: So I think the modifies of files have lost if you ditn't commit it.

Comment: Yes. And I don't want the changes also. :) Btw `git checkout .` worked and all the files came back.

Comment: Btw this might not related to the original problem.Before all these I pulled the latest, and some functionality was not working. But when I get the ZIP file from gitHub and use it those are working. Why is that ?

Comment: @prime Maybe the branch(for example `master` when downlaoding as ZIP) you download is different with the branch you pull from the remote git repo to local?

Comment: No they are all same :/

Comment: Try this: rm the `.git` directory from the git repo, then use `diff path_of_repo   path_of_download` to see what's the difference of these two directory. Hope it helps:-).